# Exception in Application start method for javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I've to problem with connecting Java program with JavaFX.

When I click on class with main→run as java application, this problems occurs:
this problem is briefly given below:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

my code is simply to add button in a layout.
my code is shown  below:

```
package application;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("shata.fxml"));
        Scene scene=new Scene(root);
        arg0.setScene(scene);
        arg0.show();
    }
}
```

My FXML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.BottomNavigation?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="179.0" prefWidth="316.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111">
   <children>
      <BottomNavigation layoutX="46.0" layoutY="51.0">
          <fx:define>
              <ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup" />
          </fx:define>
      </BottomNavigation>
      <ButtonBar layoutX="103.0" layoutY="63.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="66.0">
        <buttons>
          <Button minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" text="Button" />
        </buttons>
      </ButtonBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your shata.fxml file? The application is expecting that to be in the same directory as the Main.class.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code, but only put the Button within the AnchorPane, nothing else.

It worked fine for me. Have you tried running it without the custom ButtonNavigation? Perhaps it could be causing problems?

I often find when Java is giving med an exception regarding the FXML-file, it is caused by something different.